# Tensorflow Keras model OOM when using model.predict() although training using model.fit() runs without problems

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, out-of-memory

I'm training a model for image segmentation using tf.keras using a custom data generator to read and augment images. While training the model works fine (i.e. without memory problems), when trying to predict on my test set my GPU (8GB, see nvidia-smi later) runs out of memory. This is the case both when predicting directly after training and after restarting the kernel, loading the model using `model.load_weights()` and using `model.predict()` afterwards and with the same batch size used in training (4, using ~6GB of memory during training) or a batch size of 1 with both batch sizes trying to allocate more than 8GB.

During training, the memory usage is stable around 6GB but when using `model.predict()` it starts out at around 6GB but jumps to 8GB after approximately 10 seconds before throwing the `ResourceExhaustedError`(see later for stacktrace). This seems very counter-intuitive to me and the tips I've found through google (e.g. restarting python, loading the model from weights, then predict to free memory used beforehand) haven't worked, so any help would be great.

The output of `!nvidia-smi`, my code for the data generator and training/prediction including error messages are as follows:

## nvidia-smi

```
Mon Aug  9 14:27:29 2021       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 471.11       Driver Version: 471.11       CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ... WDDM  | 00000000:0D:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 56%   50C    P8    24W / 220W |   8057MiB /  8192MiB |      4%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1576    C+G   Insufficient Permissions        N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2292    C+G   ...kyb3d8bbwe\Calculator.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      8316    C+G   C:\Windows\explorer.exe         N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A      8736    C+G   ...lPanel\SystemSettings.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     11220    C+G   ...bbwe\Microsoft.Photos.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     11740    C+G   ...5n1h2txyewy\SearchApp.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     12280    C+G   ...ekyb3d8bbwe\YourPhone.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     12820    C+G   ...8wekyb3d8bbwe\GameBar.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     13820    C+G   ...perience\NVIDIA Share.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     14552    C+G   ...nputApp\TextInputHost.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     14848    C+G   ...y\ShellExperienceHost.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     14976    C+G   ...zilla Firefox\firefox.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     15688    C+G   ...udibleRT.WindowsPhone.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     16628      C   ...Data\Anaconda3\python.exe    N/A      |
|    0   N/A  N/A     23648    C+G   ...aming\Spotify\Spotify.exe    N/A      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

## Data Generator

```py
class DataGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, df, batch_size, mode="train", shuffle=True, augment=False, p_augment=0,
                 union=False, greyscale=False, normalize=True, dims=(256, 1600)):
        """DataGenerator usable for train/val/test splits"""
        self.df = df
        self.length = len(df)
        self.BATCH_SIZE = batch_size
        self.mode = mode
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.augment = augment
        self.p_augment = p_augment
        self.union = union
        self.greyscale = greyscale
        self.normalize = normalize
        self.dims = dims
        self.num_channels = 1 if greyscale else 3
        self.num_classes = 1 if union else 4
        self.indices = df.index.values.tolist() # will be reset anyways
        self.on_epoch_end()
        
        assert mode in ["train", "predict"], "DataGenerator mode is unsupported. Set it to \"train\" or \"predict\"."
        if augment:
            assert p_augment > 0 and p_augment <= 1, "Augmentation is turned on, but probability is zero or larger than one."
        
        
    def __len__(self):
        """number of batches in each epoch"""
        return int(np.floor(self.length / self.BATCH_SIZE))
    
    
    def on_epoch_end(self):
        """shuffle list of indices"""
        # called on the end of every epoch
        self.indices = self.df.index.values.tolist()
        if self.shuffle:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indices)
            
    
    def _load_img(self, img_path):
        """loads image in RGB/greyscale and normalizes it"""
        if self.greyscale:
            img = cv2.imread(img_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        else:
            img = cv2.imread(img_path)
            img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            
        if self.normalize:
            img = img.astype(np.float32) / 255.
        else:
            img = img.astype(np.float32)
            
        return img
    
    
    def _gen_x(self, idx_list):
        """generates input values from list of indices"""
        res = np.empty(shape=(self.BATCH_SIZE, *self.dims, self.num_channels))
        
        for i, df_idx in enumerate(idx_list):
            img_path = self.df.loc[df_idx]["img_id"]
            img = self._load_img(img_path)
            if self.greyscale:
                res[i, ] = np.expand_dims(img, axis=-1)
            else:
                res[i, ] = img
            
        return res
    
    
    def _gen_tgt(self, idx_list):
        """generates target values from list of indices"""
        res = np.empty(shape=(self.BATCH_SIZE, *self.dims, self.num_classes))
        
        for i, df_idx in enumerate(idx_list):
            rles = self.df.loc[df_idx]["c1":"c_all"]
            if self.union:
                # return mask of all defect pixels (no diff between defect class)
                masks = build_masks(rles, union_only=True)
            else:
                masks = build_masks(rles)
            res[i, ] = masks
            
        return res
    
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        """creates one batch of data"""
        # get indices of batch (self.indices is shuffled list of df indices)
        idxs = self.indices[idx*self.BATCH_SIZE:(idx+1)*self.BATCH_SIZE]
        
        x = self._gen_x(idxs)
        
        if self.mode == "predict":
            return x
        
        # mode is train -> get target data and possible augment
        tgt = self._gen_tgt(idxs)
        if self.augment:
            x, tgt = self._augment_batch(x, tgt)
        
        return x, tgt
    
    
    def _augment_batch(self, _x, _tgt):
        # flips img and masks vertically and/or horizontally with p_augment respectively
        for i in range(self.BATCH_SIZE):
            # flip up-down
            if random.random() > self.p_augment:
                if self.greyscale:
                    _x[i] = np.expand_dims(cv2.flip(_x[i], flipCode=0), axis=-1)
                else:
                    _x[i] = cv2.flip(_x[i], flipCode=0)
                _tgt[i] = cv2.flip(_tgt[i], flipCode=0)
            
            # flip left-right
            if random.random() > self.p_augment:
                if self.greyscale:
                    _x[i] = np.expand_dims(cv2.flip(_x[i], flipCode=1), axis=-1)
                else:
                    _x[i] = cv2.flip(_x[i], flipCode=1)
                _tgt[i] = cv2.flip(_tgt[i], flipCode=1)
                
        return _x, _tgt
```

## Training

```py
from copy import deepcopy

# configs for train/val datagens
train_config = {"mode": "train",
               "batch_size": 4,
               "shuffle":True,
               "augment":True,
               "p_augment": 0.5,
               "union": False,
               "greyscale": False,
               "normalize": True,
               "dims": (256,1600)}

val_config = deepcopy(train_config)
val_config["shuffle"] = False
val_config["augment"] = False

train_datagen = DataGenerator(df_train, **train_config)
val_datagen = DataGenerator(df_val, **val_config)

# returns model with correct image dims and number of classes
model = get_model_from_generator(train_datagen)
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=1e-4), loss=bce_dice_loss,
                   metrics=["binary_crossentropy", dice_coef])

cb_es = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", patience=10)
cb_best = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("models/fcn_rgb/cp_{epoch:02d}_{val_loss:.3f}.ckpt", monitor="val_loss",
                                             save_weights_only=True, save_best_only=True)
history = model.fit(x=train_datagen, callbacks=[cb_es, cb_best], epochs=100,
                           validation_data=val_datagen)
```

which trains fine (see output of first epochs)

```
Epoch 1/100
2513/2513 [==============================] - 541s 207ms/step - loss: 0.2413 - binary_crossentropy: 0.5235 - dice_coef: 0.0205 - val_loss: -0.0034 - val_binary_crossentropy: 0.1481 - val_dice_coef: 0.0775
Epoch 2/100
2513/2513 [==============================] - 518s 206ms/step - loss: -0.1231 - binary_crossentropy: 0.0864 - dice_coef: 0.1663 - val_loss: -0.2862 - val_binary_crossentropy: 0.0627 - val_dice_coef: 0.3175
```

## Prediction

Throws the same error with or without restarting the kernel after training the model.

```py
test_config = {"mode": "predict",
               "batch_size": 1,
               "shuffle":False,
               "augment":False,
               "p_augment": 0,
               "union": False,
               "greyscale": False,
               "normalize": True,
               "dims": (256,1600)}

test_datagen = DataGenerator(df_test, **test_config)
model = get_model_from_generator(train_datagen)
model.load_weights("models/fcn_rgb/cp_38_-0.497.ckpt")
preds = model.predict(test_datagen)
```

error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ResourceExhaustedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-d0a77a4d2cd0> in <module>
----> 1 preds = model.predict(test_datagen)

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1627           for step in data_handler.steps():
   1628             callbacks.on_predict_batch_begin(step)
-> 1629             tmp_batch_outputs = self.predict_function(iterator)
   1630             if data_handler.should_sync:
   1631               context.async_wait()

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    826     tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
    827     with trace.Trace(self._name) as tm:
--> 828       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    829       compiler = "xla" if self._experimental_compile else "nonXla"
    830       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    860       # In this case we have not created variables on the first call. So we can
    861       # run the first trace but we should fail if variables are created.
--> 862       results = self._stateful_fn(*args, **kwds)
    863       if self._created_variables:
    864         raise ValueError("Creating variables on a non-first call to a function"

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2940       (graph_function,
   2941        filtered_flat_args) = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
-> 2942     return graph_function._call_flat(
   2943         filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   2944 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1916         and executing_eagerly):
   1917       # No tape is watching; skip to running the function.
-> 1918       return self._build_call_outputs(self._inference_function.call(
   1919           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
   1920     forward_backward = self._select_forward_and_backward_functions(

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    553       with _InterpolateFunctionError(self):
    554         if cancellation_manager is None:
--> 555           outputs = execute.execute(
    556               str(self.signature.name),
    557               num_outputs=self._num_outputs,

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     57   try:
     58     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 59     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     60                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     61   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

ResourceExhaustedError:  OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1,96,128,800] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[node model_1/batch_normalization_57/FusedBatchNormV3 (defined at <ipython-input-16-d0a77a4d2cd0>:1) ]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
 [Op:__inference_predict_function_8858]

Function call stack:
predict_function
```

I'm using tensorflow version 2.4.1.

edit:
I forgot to mention I've also tried activation tfs dynamic memory allocation before both training and predicting with the following code, but the error still appears.

```
# dynamic memory allocation
gpus = tf.config.list_physical_devices("GPU")
if gpus:
    try:
        for gpu in gpus:
            tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
        logical_gpus = tf.config.experimental.list_logical_devices("GPU")
        print(len(gpus), "Physical GPUs,", len(logical_gpus), "Logical GPUs")
    except RuntimeError as e:
        # must be set before GPUs have been initialized
        print(e)
```

Comment: This might be silly, but is the memory usage reset to 0MiB before you restart the prediction script? `8057MiB /  8192MiB`

Comment: I too have the same question as @ML_Engine. It might be the case that the memory is already consumed by the `.fit()` and is not cleared before the `.predict()` which happened with me and I didn't diagnose the whole issue.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that by restarting the kernel/python, which clears the memory usage. The output of nvidia-smi showing `8057MiB /  8192MiB` was taken right after the error occured. Furthermore I've managed to do a workaround - when manually iterating through the dataloader (i.e. `for img in test_datagen: pred = model.predict(img)` (+storing predictions etc) yields the same memory usage of ~6GB as training. Doesn't really make sense to my why this would be, but at least it's working so far.

Comment: I cant see where you're defining your model. Are you sure it's being trained on the GPU?

Comment: Yes I didn't include the exact model definition as the post was very long already. I'm initialising my model with `model = get_model_from_generator(train_datagen)` which takes parameters such as number of channels/classes from the data generator to initialise it. I'm sure my model is training and predicting on the GPU as I can see the rise/fall of vRAM usage and GPU load change during training and prediction time using GPU-Z.

Comment: That strange behavior is probably a known memory leak: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64199384/tf-keras-model-predict-results-in-memory-leak