# I'm getting an unexpected Tensorflow ResourceExhaustedError when I try to use model.predict() with a Keras Sequential model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, out-of-memory

I'm using `Python 3.9`, and I have `Tensorflow 2.10` installed with `CUDA Toolkit 11.2` and `cuDNN 8.2`, as this was the last configuration to be supported natively on `Windows 10`.

I'm training using an NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 SUPER with 8Gb of VRAM, and I have 64 Gb of RAM on my PC.

I've used `Keras` to create a Sequential model to predict POS-tags. I've used the same model format to train models for text in several different languages. The models all trained alright, and when I run `model.evaluate(test_data)` they all produce a score. Similarly, when I run `model.predict(test_data)` most models produce the expected results, but there is one model, for one language, which acts differently.

This one model was trained the same as all the other models, so there should be no difference I think. When I run `model.predict(test_data)` using this model, at first it seems to be working. It starts applying the model to the dataset:

```
  6/152 [=>............................] - ETA: 19s
```

It even appears to successfully complete this step, though it never gets as far as producing any results:

```
152/152 [==============================] - 20s 126ms/step
```

Unfortunately at this point it hangs and produces the following traceback:

```
2024-01-05 23:08:38.977923: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:479] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 2.61GiB (rounded to 2804106240)requested by op ConcatV2
If the cause is memory fragmentation maybe the environment variable 'TF_GPU_ALLOCATOR=cuda_malloc_async' will improve the situation. 
Current allocation summary follows.
...
...
...
2024-01-05 23:08:38.998922: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1101] Sum Total of in-use chunks: 4.04GiB
2024-01-05 23:08:38.998977: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] total_region_allocated_bytes_: 6263144448 memory_limit_: 6263144448 available bytes: 0 curr_region_allocation_bytes_: 8589934592
2024-01-05 23:08:38.999071: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1109] Stats: 
Limit:                      6263144448
InUse:                      4335309312
MaxInUse:                   4520417536
NumAllocs:                        1293
MaxAllocSize:                536870912
Reserved:                            0
PeakReserved:                        0
LargestFreeBlock:                    0

2024-01-05 23:08:38.999241: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:491] ****************x*****************************************************______________________________
2024-01-05 23:08:38.999336: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1780] OP_REQUIRES failed at concat_op.cc:158 : RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[38688,18120] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admd9\PycharmProjects\codalab-sigtyp2024\generate_results.py", line 131, in <module>
    predictions = task_model.predict(test_gen)
  File "C:\Users\admd9\anaconda3\envs\tf_codalab_sharedtask\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\admd9\anaconda3\envs\tf_codalab_sharedtask\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 7209, in raise_from_not_ok_status
    raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: {{function_node __wrapped__ConcatV2_N_152_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0}} OOM when allocating tensor with shape[38688,18120] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc [Op:ConcatV2] name: concat
```

I can't work out why it's only happening with this one model, or why there would be a problem with memory allocation when it works for all the other models. It doesn't seem like it's trying to use a lot of memory either. So why am I getting this error message? And, how can I fix it?

I've tried setting memory growth, but it didn't work:

```
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
```

I've also reduced batch sizes. This didn't help. I've even gone back and retrained the model in case there was something wrong with the model itself. Still have the same problem with the new model. As a last option, I tried splitting the test set into smaller divisions, running `model.predict(test_data)` on each of these divisions, then recombining the results of each division. It sometimes successfully predicts the first division, but always runs out of memory and gives me the same error by the second division.

Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 0):

In case this is useful to anybody else who's having the same problem, this is how I overcame it. If an error occurs when making predictions using the GPU, I switch to using the CPU instead. This way the GPU memory won't be exhausted because the system memory is being utilised instead of it.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Make predictions with model
# Try to make predictions using GPU first
try:
    with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
        predictions = model.predict(test_data)
# If the GPU prediction fails (eg. due to memory error) attempt prediction using CPU instead
except:
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        predictions = model.predict(test_data)
```

This worked for me, but using the CPU can be a lot slower particularly if the test set is large. I also don't necessarily want to except all errors by switching to the CPU. I would like to be more specific with the `except` statement, but the error message I'd been getting seems to be a discrete tensorflow error: `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError`. I wasn't sure how to except only this.

I'm not going to accept this answer because I don't think it's a great solution. I'd still be grateful if anybody can provide a better solution which does not require using the CPU, but this was the best workaround I could come up with.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that either your model or your `test_data` is too big to fit into your GPU memory. If it is the latter, you can try to stream the data using a [`tf.data.Dataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) object, maybe something like this would work:

```
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(test_data)
predictions = model.predict(test_dataset)
```

If you are already sending the data to the GPU in batches, then reducing the `batch_size` for prediction might help too by using `model.predict(..., batch_size=<your_choice>)`.

UPDATE:

I saw that the `predict` function was leaking in previous versions, and maybe the problem is still present in TF 2.10:

- TF 2.3 : [tf.keras model.predict results in memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64199384/tf-keras-model-predict-results-in-memory-leak)
- TF 2.8 : [tensorflow model predict runs out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74715393/tensorflow-model-predict-runs-out-of-memory)

So maybe you can try one of the workarounds mentioned there, or just upgrade...

Comment: Hey, thanks for the insight. I think it's probably the former. It is a relatively large model (for the GPU I'm using at least) and I am using a data generator to send batches to the GPU. Reducing the batch size doesn't help, and batch size would probably have caused a problem during training if that was the problem, not during testing. What's interesting is that `model.evaluate(test_data)` works fine, and `model.predict(test_data)` seems to get through all of the test set, as I showed above. It only runs out of memory as the method finishes working and tries to return its predictions.

Comment: Maybe the `predict` function is still leaking memory in TF2.10.

Comment: Maybe. I came across this issue when looking into this problem at first, but I thought it had been solved after Tf 2.4. I tried some of the solutions, including `gc.collect()`, but that didn't seem to work for me. I'll try a few more and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Tried a few different things, including running `keras.backend.clear_session()` before running the `model.predict()` method. Unfortunately, nothing allowed it to run on the GPU successfully.